# how i can set background image in my app by code and save the setting

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

How can I set a background image in my app by code and save the setting?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

If you put your image in the `Assets` folder for example you can always use this image as the background with something like this

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/MyImage.png" />
    </Grid.Background>
</Grid>
```